# Call a function from the host application

Tags: delphi, components

I want to call a function from my host application in my new component.
Basically I want to call a function from an other project.

Is there any possible way to do so?

The component is a navigator and a search function should be called, which is coded in an other project.

Comment: The simple answer is that yes, it is possible for code to call functions. Exactly how that is done depends on the organisation of your code. The other function is part of the same process? In which case call it. It is part of a different process? Then you need some form of IPC.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The navigator needs an host application to be compiled. It is used in the host application. So i guess it is the same process. The function only should be called if the host application is an defined application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting for the component to be able to call a function in its host. The component should not know the internal details of its host which is why you are unable to simply call the function. Solve the problem by having the host supply a callback function to the component.

For instance you might go about it this way:

1. Add an event to your component to represent the search function callback.
2. When the component needs to perform search functionality, it should call the event handler, if one has been provided.
3. Implement a handler for this event in your host project.
4. In the host project, when the component has been created, set the event property to refer to your event handler.

This is entirely analagous to how the `OnClick` event handler for a `TButton` works. The button control is analagous to your component. The button knows nothing about the host application. When it needs to respond to being clicked, it fires the event provided by the host application.

Comment: Worked like a charm!